# State update doesn't re-render component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in which I have this useEffect:

```
  const [charactersInfo, setCharactersInfo] = useState(null);

  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api/api/character/?page=${page}`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setCharactersInfo(result);
      });
  }, [page]);
```

whenever my `page` state updates there is different data coming from the api as expected. but issue is whenever new `setCharactersInfo(result)` happens, it does not display the new data.

I am passing my `setPage` state function to this component as a prop:

```
   <PaginationButtons
          data={charactersInfo}
          updatePage={(number) => {
            setPage(number);
          }}
        />
```

This is re-usable component which generates buttons and it works correctly everywhere except this specific component. any suggestions please?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./PaginationButtons.css";

function PaginationButtons({ data, updatePage }) {
  const [buttonsArr, setButtonsArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const finalArray = [];
    const { info } = data;
    // Not the best solution for situations in which
    // info.pages is big number(e.x 1000000) but since we know that
    // it mostly will be 34 or less so we can just loop through it :)
    for (let i = 1; i < info.pages + 1; i++) {
      finalArray.push(
        <button
          className="page_button"
          onClick={() => updatePage(i)}
          key={Math.random()}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    setButtonsArr(finalArray);
  }, []);
  return <div className="button_container">{buttonsArr.map((el) => el)}</div>;
}

export default PaginationButtons;
```

data prop is an object which contains various of stuff and on the them is the number of pages that should be displayed. in this specific case it 34 for so I use state and useEffect to loop through this number and store buttons in the state array and map it afterwards

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code? Can you share `PaginationButtons` component code?

Comment: @DrewReese sure just a moment

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the question with PaginationButtons code

Comment: I think you are missing data dependency in useEffect of PaginationButtons

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `data` change in your child component as well.
pass `data` to useEffect dependency list.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const finalArray = [];
    const { info } = data;
    // Not the best solution for situations in which
    // info.pages is big number(e.x 1000000) but since we know that
    // it mostly will be 34 or less so we can just loop through it :)
    for (let i = 1; i < info.pages + 1; i++) {
      finalArray.push(
        <button
          className="page_button"
          onClick={() => updatePage(i)}
          key={Math.random()}
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      );
    }
    setButtonsArr(finalArray);
  }, [data]);
```

This should help you, no need to maintain state. and i see pages is not array its just key value pair.

```
function PaginationButtons({ data, updatePage }) {
 const { info : { pages } } = data;
  return (
    <div className="button_container">
       <button
          className="page_button"
          onClick={() => updatePage(pages || 0)}
          key={pages}
        >
          {pages || 0}
        </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: sadly it didn't fix it :(

Comment: pls check new ans

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` in `PaginationButtons` is using an empty dependency so it doesn't update when the `data` prop updates. From what I can tell you don't need the `buttonsArr` state anyway. It's also anti-pattern to store derived state from props. Just map the `data` array prop to the buttons.

Using random values is probably the least ideal method of specifying React keys. You can use the mapped array index, but you should use a unique property for each page element, or if there isn't one you should augment the data with a generated GUID.

```
function PaginationButtons({ data, updatePage }) {
  return (
    <div className="button_container">
      {data.?info?.pages?.map((page, i) => (
        <button
          className="page_button"
          onClick={() => updatePage(i)}
          key={i} // <-- or page.id if available
        >
          {i}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: data prop is an object which contains various of stuff and on the them is  the number of pages that should be displayed. in this specific case it 34 for so I use state and useEffect to loop through this number and store buttons in the state array and map it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other answers, you need to add `data` as a dependency. Also,  you don't need to call `map` on `buttonsArr`, as you're not doing anything with its elements. Just use `buttonsArr` itself